# Error compiling SWIG wrapper

Tags: python, c++, swig

I'm trying to wrap some C++ functions in Python using SWIG. Following the tutorial, I wrote an interface file

```
%module rasnetclient
%{
#include "rasnetclientcomm.hh"
%}
RasnetClientComm(std::string rasmgrHost, int rasmgrPort);
RasnetClientCommDestroy();

int connectClient(std::string userName, std::string passwordHash);
int disconnectClient();
```

and generated a wrapper. However, when I try to compile it using `g++ -c -std=c++0x rasnetclientcomm.cc rasnetclient_wrap.c -I /usr/include/python2.7` I get the following errors:

```
rasnetclient_wrap.c: In function 'PyObject* _wrap_connectClient(PyObject*, PyObject*)':
rasnetclient_wrap.c:3383:40: error: 'connectClient' was not declared in this scope
rasnetclient_wrap.c: In function 'PyObject* _wrap_disconnectClient(PyObject*, PyObject*)':
rasnetclient_wrap.c:3396:34: error: 'disconnectClient' was not declared in this scope
```

Am I doing something wrong with the definition of the interface file? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried including all the definitions in a single header file?

Comment: All the definitions are in a single header file: So, the files are rasnetclientcomm.hh, rasnetclientcomm.cc, rasnetclient.i, and rasnetclient_wrap.c

Comment: It will be better if you can reduce your code to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post it.

Comment: It's a lot of stuff within the function calls which is referring to other libraries. So, reducing is moot. All I want to do is to wrap some of the functions in a given c++ file into Python so I call them from Python. Also, the swig interface files does a pretty decent job of giving an idea of header file since it's basically almost a copy paste of headers.